# Angular2 Animation for simple hover, without any state change

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I need help with ng2 animate. I need to prepare simple hover effect based on this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'category',
    template : require('./category.component.html'),
    styleUrls: ['./category.component.scss'],
    animations: [
        trigger('albumState', [
            state('inactive', style({
                bottom: '0px'
            })),
            state('active', style({
                bottom: '200px'
            })),
            transition('inactive => active', animate('100ms ease-in')),
            transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-in'))
        ])
    ]
})
```

I need a hint how can I assign that to the template? On Ng2 Docs, we have implementation base on object parameter. I don't need to change any parameter of my

```
item/object/album
```

from the **category**, just want assign animation to template.

Regards!
Greg

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are not using the "bottom" property as a hover, any regular ":hover" pseudo class will work. For example:

```
.album:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Support for pseudo classes within the state is yet a [feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10196)

Possible workaround: Add a parent to your element by wrapping it, then add the `:hover` pseudoclass to this parent.

```
<span class="parent">
    <div class="album">...</div>
</span>
```

Then

```
.parent:hover {
    bottom:50px; // or what you want to achieve here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to override a property being set by the Angular animation you could always use `!important`.

```
.album:hover {
  bottom: 20px !important;
}
```

Using the important flag is not the most desirable solution, but it will work until we get support for pseudo classes in Angular animation.